# Prevent dismissal of UIAlertController when pressing button

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Is it a way not to dismiss `UIAlertController` right after pressing button, `UIAlertAction`?

I do not want validate textfield. But wait until. quick webservice call responds.